# Can erlang:system_time/1 ever return a negative number?

Tags: erlang

Can `erlang:system_time/1` ever return a negative number?

`erlang:system_time/1` is [specced to return `integer()`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#system_time-1). Would `non_neg_integer()` or `pos_integer()` be more correct and more precise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`erlang:system_time` gives the time since Epoch. Epoch is defined to be `00:00:00 UTC, 1970-01-01.` So it cannot give a negative value or zero as the response. So, I think `pos_integer()` would be the more accurate spec.